# How can I call a function only once in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I have been trying to start using typescript for react native but it has not been easy ride so far, finding it difficult to perform common function like fetch an api once on screen load, below is the current function am using but I dont want to use time outs plus its not even working properly(it has to wait for the actual time I set before it runs and its bad for android), I would like to call the function only once when the page loads, I have also tried using if else statements but I dont know why it not just working on typescript.

```
 (function(){  
   setTimeout(function () {
const newsUrl = 'http://172.20.10.4:8000/mobile/news';
    return fetch(newsUrl, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
          }
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            let newArr = [...data];
            setProducts(newArr);
            //console.log(data);
            alert(38783763);
          
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
           console.error(error);
         });
       }, 200); 

}.call(this));
```

Comment: If you start learning typescript without react knowledge it will be a 90deg vertical uphill battle.

Comment: The question should read, "How can I call a function only once in React?".

Comment: @Khant. It makes more sense to get comfortable with JavaScript, then Typescript and then start using React.

Comment: @Obyno Pac any update on this?

Comment: @axtck I used useEffect

Comment: @ObynoPac you can mark the answer as accepted if you like (if it fixed your problem)

Comment: Yes , I already marked it as answer by clicking on the arrow pointing upwards

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `useEffect` hook and pass an empty array the fetch data once on load.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(newsUrl, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
          }
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            let newArr = [...data];
            setProducts(newArr);
        })
}, []);
```